# Can I change battery meter display to (actualReading/85)*100?

Tags: battery, battery-life, screen, android-13

Can I change my battery meter to display the value `(actualReading/85)*100` instead of actualReading? so when it's at 85% it displays 100%, and when it's at 50% it displays as 58%, when it's 10% it displays as 11% and so on?

My phone (a Samsung Galaxy S22 Ultra) has a optional `battery protect mode` which stops charging at 85%, which supposedly extends the battery life, and I'm testing it out, but it's annoying to see 85% when that's "the new 100%",

it would reduce my cognitive load if I could change the display % to the formula `(actualReading/85)*100`,

Is that possible?

Phone is rooted, if that helps. It's also stuck on Android 13 (cannot upgrade it to android 14 without wiping it, due to rooting, AFAIK)